# String manipulation in Mac terminal

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh

Do you know why this is not working?

Note I am on a Mac terminal with ~/.zshrc

```
FOO="MACOS"
FOO=${FOO//$OS/}
echo $FOO
```

echo:

```
MACOS
```

I expect it to echo `MAC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `FOO=${FOO//$OS/}` to `FOO=${FOO//OS/}` and it should fly then. Why because `$` we use when we want to print value of any variable but in this case it is NOT variable it is a string which we are mentioning(tested on BASH).

In case you want to use `$`(which we could use by creating another variable which have value of string `OS`) then try following.

```
os="OS"            ##Creating a variable named os with string value OS.
FOO="MACOS"        ##Creating variable FOO with value of string MACOS.
FOO=${FOO//$os/}   ##Using variable expansion of BASH to remove variable `os` value from variable `FOO` here and saving it into `FOO` variable itself.
echo "$FOO"        ##Printing value of variable `$FOO` here.
MAC
```